Issue Connecting to MongoDB Atlas on Heroku for an Increment System
I am facing difficulties with my MongoDB Atlas database that works fine locally but does not function on Heroku. My goal is to implement an increment system for a "like" counter on my animals.
I have configured my cluster correctly and performed local tests to verify that my remote database on MongoDB Atlas increments properly when I click the button. Everything works on port 4000 locally.
However, when I deploy my application on Heroku and perform the same test, an error occurs. I have modified the link in my script to point to my Heroku app URL. I also configured the environment variable for my MongoDB connection string.
Here’s the code I am using for the increment:
document
  .getElementById("increment-xxx")
  .addEventListener("click", async () => {
    try {
      // Utilisation de l'API locale, mais qui pointe vers MongoDB Atlas
      const response = await fetch(
        "http://localhost:4000/animal/xxx/click",
        {
          method: "POST",
        }
      );

      if (response.ok) {
        const data = await response.json();
        console.log("Compteur xxx incrémenté:", data);
        document.getElementById(
          "result"
        ).innerHTML = `Godzilla: ${data.animal.views}`;
      } else if (response.status === 404) {
        console.error("Animal non trouvé");
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Animal non trouvé.";
      } else {
        console.error(
          "Erreur lors de l'incrémentation du compteur:",
          response.statusText
        );
      }

I'm looking for help, otherwise I can't get my MongoDB database to work on Heroku.

We can't possibly help you if you just tell us "an error occurs" without telling us what the exact error is. It's like going to the doctor and telling them just "it hurts".
